# Import abbreviations for common modules

Tags: python, naming-conventions

[Google's style guide](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/pyguide.md#22-imports) says, about imports, that modules might be aliased with `import xyz as x` when `x` is a common abbreviation for `xyz`.

What are the standard abbreviations for the most common modules?

I'm here looking for a list exhaustive as possible, including modules from the standard library, as well as third-party niche packages that are frequently used in their respective fields.

For instance, `numpy` is always imported as `np`, and `tkinter`, when hopefully not imported with `from module import *`, is generally imported as `tk`.

Comment: *most common modules*: IMHO, it is a broad notion. For example, you listed "tkinter" as a common module but which  Python web developer will never use or even hear about. In general, just refer to the documentation of the module you want to you use and you will get information about its standard import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the names I see most of the time for the modules I frequently use.
This list is not meant to become an absolute reference, but I hope it will help provide some guidelines.
Please feel free to complete it, or to change whatever you think needs to be changed.

The import statements follow the conventions established by [Google's Python style guide](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/pyguide.md#22-imports), namely:

- Use `import x` for importing packages and modules.
- Use `from x import y` where `x` is the package prefix and `y` is the module name with no prefix.
- Use from `x import y as z` if two modules named `y` are to be imported or if `y` is an inconveniently long name.
- Use `import y as z` only when `z` is a standard abbreviation (e.g., `np` for `numpy`).

---

```
MODULE                  ALIAS       IMPORT STATEMENT

datetime                dt          import datetime as dt
matplotlib.pyplot       plt         from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
multiprocessing         mp          import multiprocessing as mp
numpy                   np          import numpy as np
pandas                  pd          import pandas as pd
seaborn                 sns         import seaborn as sns 
tensorflow              tf          import tensorflow as tf
tkinter                 tk          import tkinter as tk
```